# Error is breaking the for loop: conditional try statement?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have a for loop in R:

```
for i in seq(1 , nrow(df)){
  try(function(i),silent=T)
}
```

I would like to revise this so that if an error message shows up, the function repeats the for loop one more time. If it fails again -

```
message(paste("function failed twice for", i))
```

`

Is try() the proper function for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any R but my guess is that you can do something like this:

```
errorCount = 0
for i in seq(1 , nrow(df)){
  tryCatch(function(i),silent=T, 
          error = {errorCount +=1,
          tryCatch(function(i), silent=T, 
                   error = {errorCount +=1
                            print("2 times error")
                            tryCatch(function(i), silent=T, 
                            error = {errorCount +=1
                            tryCatch(function(i), silent=T, 
                            error = {print("3 times error: Did not repeat")
                                     break})
                            } )
                   })
          )
}
```

Sorry about my terrible code - I made it happen 3 times as you specified, but you'll have to fix the syntax. Other answers are recommended.